# Exercises in predicate calculus

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Can anybody recommend me a book with examples and exercises on deducibility in (axiomatic) predicate calculus? It's strange, I see many similar texts about propositional calculus, but not about predicate one. This is for teaching, thank you.

Comment: What kind of system of predicate calculus? Axiomatic, natural deduction, tableaux, sequent? If e.g. natural deduction, Fitch-style, Gentzen-style, Lemmon-style? And so it goes ... We can't really respond your request until we know what you are actually after!

Comment: I mean axiomatic, excuse me.

Comment: The choice of a textbook also depends on the students' background. For example, is it a class for students majoring in a Mathematics, Computer Science or Philosophy?

Comment: I don't know of a single book... Can anybody advise anything?

Comment: This is for students specialized in Mathematics, maybe applied, this depends of the future choice of profession. But in my opinion, this is not very important.